# elementary OS Boot Error

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, boot, uefi

When I am trying to boot from my USB to install elementary OS,
 it shows me an error.

```
Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: please see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402256/boot-with-ubuntu-livecd-gives-an-error-message-before-proceeding-to-a-grub-style) if useful =)

Comment: After the error it showed me GNU GRUB. I didn't get to GRUB menu.

Comment: did you see grub>_

Comment: I had to press tab to show options. I had seen boot so I typed it but it said "you need to load kernel first".

Comment: Are you able to select "Try elementary" ?

Comment: No, after the error it showed me GNU GRUB instantly. I have no options.

Comment: It's single boot and I can post pictures but in low quality.

Comment: Picture: http://i.imgur.com/QoLPGN0.jpg

Comment: that link seems to be complex, Have you waited some time after login to live usb, as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402256/boot-with-ubuntu-livecd-gives-an-error-message-before-proceeding-to-a-grub-style)

Comment: btw how you created live usb? try to create live usb with other tool.

Comment: I created live usb with rufus. And I waited for 10 minutes and nothing happened.

Comment: Is there any OS installed on system?

Comment: Yes, right now I have windows 8.1 pro 64-bit

Comment: have a look [here](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)

Comment: It still gets me to GNU GNUB.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31766/discussion-on-question-by-mike-griniezakis-elementary-os-boot-error).

Comment: @Tim to my memory the system covers that.

Comment: @Tim when comments are moved to chat a special room is created that the user can access (to my memory) even if they don't have 20 rep.

Comment: Try SO starting http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/ "Rescatux".
Rescatux allows correcting different types of errors with respect to the GRUB and other errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a running linux system.

Plug USB

```
sudo parted /dev/sdX set 1 boot on
sudo mount /dev/sdX1 /mnt
sudo 7z x /path-to-iso -o/mnt/
```

Where X is your USB device (usualmente a)

Answer (score 1):

Disable (U)EFI on bios and try.